# Как убрать зависимости в скомпилированном файле JS у Webpack?

Tags: webpack

Webpack после компиляции JavaScript оставляет вначале большой кусок кода. 
Насколько понял, это зависимости модулей и общая техническая информация. 
Так ли она нужна на продакшене? даже если пишу совсем маленький скрипт
И как ее убрать? 
Пробовал указать разные **devtool** из [документации](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/), не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это работет если у вас пара зависимостей. Но если работать с фреймворком, то они могут конфликтовать или загружаться по нескольку раз. Модули должны быть загруженны в определённом порядке, а если продакшн порезан на чанки, то гарантировать порядок призван этот код спереди.

Comment: А если код без фреймворков? Как-то можно отключить генерацию зависимостей? Например, Чистый JavaScript и Sass. А webpack нужен, чтобы кроссбраузерность добавлять (babel, autoprefixer и т.п.)

Comment: бабельнуть можно без вэбпака

Comment: Так babel уже стоит =) билд отличный, вот единственный минус - лишний код генерируется. Без него было бы "зе бест"

Comment: Запусти профилирование, посмотри много ли теряешь на этом лишнем коде. Ведь меньше долей секунды он займёт

Comment: то есть выход один - смириться? я пока нашел выход - использовать Gulp, где компиляция чистая без следов Gulp

Comment: Есть rollup.js тоже хороший сборщик без over head

Answer (score 1):

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true,
}
```

Или используйте [webpack-merge-and-include-globally](https://github.com/markshapiro/webpack-merge-and-include-globally)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Интересное решение. При таком подходе исходный файл js делится на 2. Причем нужный гораздо меньше, чем в обычном режиме. всего 1 строка лишняя console.log('test') выдает (window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[1],[function(o,n){console.log("test")}],[[0,3]]]);

Comment: Я уточнил у разработчиков. Сказали, что такого лишнего кода не будет в Webpack 5. И добавили - Webpack 4 это сборщик, а не компилятор, поэтому зависимости будут. Если не нужны зависимости, значит не нужна сборка, тогда и скорее всего не нужен webpack. B посоветовали использовать другую программу =)

Comment: То отмазки со стороны разрабов. До 4 небыло такого поведения и в 5 не будет, зато здесь - это нома. Смешные

Comment: Вот я и дождался webpack 5. Колбаса вверху стала еще больше =) Похоже, только gulp работает чисто